# How to count the number of nodes of both sides of all nodes in a binary tree

Tags: c++, c++17

I want the solution for all nodes, not for a single node! I have applied BFS/DFS for every node to calculate its nodes of one side but the complexity is very high. And I know that if I can find the  nodes of one side, nodes of other side can be calculated by doing (n-(nodes of one side)).

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 2):

You can compute the numbers making a single tree traversal with:

```
void computeCounters(Node *n) {
    if (n) {
        if (n->left) {
            computeCounters(n->left);
            n->leftCount = 1 + n->left->leftCount + n->left->rightCount;
        } else {
            n->leftCount = 0;
        }
        if (n->right) {
            computeCounters(n->right);
            n->rightCount = 1 + n->right->leftCount + n->right->rightCount;
        } else {
            n->rightCount = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much for you answer. I don't know why my question was edited automatically. What I actually wanted to know is that suppose, I have a connected graph with n-1 edges. Now, I remove one of the edges so the graph divided into two parts. I calculate the number of nodes in any one of the parts and store it. Now, I replace the edge. Then, I remove another edge and do the same. I want to do the same thing for all edges and store them! How to do this without applying bfs/dfs n-1 times? @6502